# Unable to get elements within String[][] to be included in a single data structure in Scala

Tags: scala

What I'm trying here is that by iterating a `Array[Array[String]]`, so that I can get them in a kind of Map (`Bson` or `Document` as it is related to the MongoDB libs).

```
val document = Document()
  structure
    .map(arr => Document(arr(0) -> arr(1)))
    .foreach(element => document ++ element)
  document
```

Whenever that code is executed, none happens to the original `document` and everything stays the same, meaning that `document` is still empty.

Should I iterate it out of a lambda function?

Comment: Note that `String[][]` is Java-speak. In Scala we say `Array[Array[String]]`.

Comment: Absolutely @SethTisue, just updated the question. Constantly shifting Java and Scala does no good at times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` is immutable reference, so after you set `val document` to `Document()` it doesn't change.

You `.foreach(element => document ++ element)` creates new object which is not preserved anywhere - `++` creates a new object, it doesn't update the old one!

If you want to have a map there, build the map before putting it into the document:

```
val document = Document(
  structure
    .map(arr => arr(0) -> arr(1))
    .toMap
)
```

or store the result of combination into value:

```
val document = structure
  .map(arr => arr(0) -> arr(1))
  .foldLeft(Document()) { (aggregatedDocument, nextDocument) =>
    aggregatedDocument ++ nextDocument
  }
```

If you insist on mutating (I do not recommend that if you don't have a good reason)

```
// var - variable, mutable
// val - value, immutable
var document = Document()
structure
  .map(arr => Document(arr(0) -> arr(1)))
  .foreach(element => document = document ++ element)
```